# Active Admin on Heroku doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activeadmin

Hi I had active admin working fine before but I think it got messed up when I tried merging my github + heroku repositories. It seems to work fine locally but on Heroku I get the generic We're sorry, but something went wrong message.  Here is the output of my heroku logs

> 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   `_run_process_action_callbacks' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   __run_callback' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in
>   `block in process_action' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in`process_action' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in
>   `instrument' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in`
>   block in instrument' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in
>   `instrument' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in`
>   process_action' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in
>   `process_action' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`
>   process_action' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in`
>   process' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in
>   `dispatch' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   myrealtrip.com/admin/login dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=488ms
>   status=500 bytes=643 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in`
>   dispatch' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in
>   `block in action' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in
>   `dispatch' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:40:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in`
>   block in call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in
>   `each' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`
>   block in call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in
>   `catch' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in`call'
>   2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in`call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in
>   `context' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in`
>   block in call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   `__run_callback' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`
>   _run_call_callbacks' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   `_run__1275827987324005955__call__874682597306149572__callbacks'
>   2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`
>   run_callbacks' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in
>   `call_app' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
>   2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in
>   `forward' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in`
>   fetch' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in
>   `lookup' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in`
>   call!' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in
>   `call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in
>   `service' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in`
>   call' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
>   2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in`run'
>   2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in
>   start_thread' 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:  2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00
>   app[web.1]: Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new
>   as HTML 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-ecb9ade65394/app/views/active_admin/devise/shared/_links.erb
>   (1.6ms) 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-ecb9ade65394/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
>   within layouts/active_admin_logged_out (379.1ms)
>   2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server
>   Error in 458ms 2012-05-08T08:20:16+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   myrealtrip.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms
>   status=200 bytes=0 2012-05-08T08:20:20+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   www.myrealtrip.com/assets/twit_icon_s.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms
>   service=7ms status=200 bytes=2504 2012-05-08T08:20:20+00:00
>   heroku[router]: GET www.myrealtrip.com/assets/fb_icon_s.png dyno=web.1
>   queue=0 wait=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=2498
>   2012-05-08T08:20:20+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   myrealtrip.com/assets/application.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms
>   service=12ms status=200 bytes=74016 2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00
>   app[web.1]:  2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/ko/offers/16" for
>   125.129.240.184 at 2012-05-08 08:20:21 +0000 2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by OffersController#show as HTML
>   2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered offers/show.html.erb
>   within layouts/application (7.8ms) 2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"locale"=>"ko", "id"=>"16"}
>   2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
>   layouts/_header.html.erb (1.9ms) 2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms) 2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00
>   app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 11.4ms | ActiveRecord:
>   5.3ms) 2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.myrealtrip.com/ko/offers/16 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms
>   service=57ms status=200 bytes=11374 2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00
>   heroku[router]: GET myrealtrip.com/assets/mrt_logo.png dyno=web.1
>   queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=1985
>   2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   www.myrealtrip.com/assets/application-e7fd2f7d29fd91d2ef43a8f52446d55e.css
>   dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0
>   2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   www.myrealtrip.com/assets/application-970c5c7eca4b286b5184e3caddf2b448.js
>   dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=23ms status=304 bytes=0
>   2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   www.myrealtrip.com/assets/fb_icon_s-41437f3d5d3a5b299e347aa41b1757bc.png
>   dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
>   2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   www.myrealtrip.com/assets/twit_icon_s-2a91a32dd31f44cdc2716db595394a4e.png
>   dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
>   2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   www.myrealtrip.com/assets/product_icon-de97603b22ca0e28730a4039f538c986.png
>   dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0
>   2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   www.myrealtrip.com/assets/offer_m_16-c77ea7c8aa397099eba93efd10f2ed0e.jpg
>   dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
>   2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   www.myrealtrip.com/assets/guide_icon-0918b097277ab00b11c74d9a29601af1.png
>   dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=0
>   2012-05-08T08:20:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   www.myrealtrip.com/assets/guide_profile_m_10-aae5b6874e3f733c238dde938cc90f09.jpg
>   dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
>   2012-05-08T08:20:22+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   www.myrealtrip.com/assets/mrt_logo.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms
>   service=5ms status=304 bytes=0 2012-05-08T08:20:22+00:00
>   heroku[router]: GET www.myrealtrip.com/assets/register_icon.png
>   dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=14694
>   2012-05-08T08:20:23+00:00 heroku[router]: GET
>   www.myrealtrip.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms
>   status=304 bytes=0

Comment: fixed it with this in config/environments/production.rb


config.assets.compile = true

:(

Comment: I was able to get it working by setting `config.assets.precompile += %w(active_admin.css active_admin.js)` in application.rb file. I have `config.assets.compile = false` in production.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it with this in config/environments/production.rb config.assets.compile = true :(

Comment: In production mode every request to assets will start chain of additional methods to compile and serve asset in runtime when config.assets.compile = true. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

An update to this - heroku have provided a new experimental feature that brings the asset compilation more inline with what is happening in the development environment.

From your app root run:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

You should not need to make any of the change mentioned above, and should remove them if you have made them. The other fix touted is to add the following to config/application.rb (again you should not need this):

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
config.assets.precompile += %w[active_admin.css active_admin.js print.css]
config.assets.precompile += %w[active_admin/print.css]
```

Read more here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

Answer (score 0):

active admin is working fine in heroku ..see this http://getinvoice.herokuapp.com/admin..
This is view level problem .you should resolve it by removing one by one view ...then fine where is the problem.........